# WebGL with a cross-compiler like GWT (recommendations)

Tags: gwt, cross-compiling, webgl

I'd like to try out WebGL but do not like JavaScript that much. Are there any *-to-JavaScript compilers like [GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit) (Java to JavaScript) which you can recommend for WebGL development?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[GwtGl](http://code.google.com/p/gwtgl/) allows the use of WebGL in a GWT project.

Answer (score 3):

I've found [gwt-g3d](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-g3d/) to be the best.

Examples worked the first time for me and it comes with lots of useful utilities e.g. common shader types, common matrix functions etc.

Answer (score 3):

I also vote for GwtGL! It was very easy to write WebGL applications with this wrapper. I can use all benefits from Java and interact with other, state of the art,  javascript libraries like gl-matrix to get matrix functions. I've written some posts how to use GwtGL based on the famous learningwebgl.com tutorials here http://gibberfish.net/learning-webgl-lesson-1-with-gwtgl/.